# Postfix: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table, even though recipient domain is an external domain

Tags: postfix

In my company infrastructure, I have an internal mail server with postfix whose name is, say, **srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld** with internal IP 10.10.128.200.

For exchanging mails with the Net, it uses a **relay mail server** (a server on a DMZ environment with all needed pinholes for instance ..), even with postfix, whose name is **mailgw.central.mydomain.tld** with internal interface IP 10.10.133.105

Public domain name of our infrastructure is (say) "**central.mydomain.tld**", *but "**pec.central.mydomain.tld**" IS NOT our subdomain*. It is provided by another ISP outside our network (so, mails to this domain, have to get out).

If I send a mail from *user1@central.mydomain.tld* (from srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld machine) to ***foo@pec.central.mydomain.tld***, I get from relay server the following error:

```
Sep  4 08:03:16 mailgw postfix/smtpd[26678]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[10.10.128.200]: 550 5.1.1 <foo@pec.central.mydomain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table; from=<user1@central.mydomain.tld> to=<foo@pec.central.mydomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld>
Sep  4 08:03:16 mailgw postfix/smtpd[26678]: disconnect from unknown[10.10.128.200]
```

My relay server is on Linux CentOS release 5.7, postfix release is postfix-2.3.3-2.1.el5_2 from standard CentOS repositories.

Let's say my domain is:

```
 mydomain = central.mydomain.tld
```

And my postfix configuration on relay server, currenttly is the following:

(postconf -d; postconf -d; postconf -n; ) | sort | uniq -u

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
content_filter = filter:127.0.0.1:10025
default_process_limit = 10
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 12582912
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
myhostname = mailgw.$mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.10.24.0/24, 10.10.128.200/32, 10.10.128.201/32
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /etc/postfix/README_FILES
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
relay_domains = $mydomain, riminiventure.it
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
sample_directory = /etc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 5s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 10
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,    permit_sasl_authenticated,    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_client,    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_helo,    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_sender, pcre:/etc/postfix/access_sender_pcre,    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_recipient,    reject_unauth_destination,    reject_invalid_hostname,    reject_unauth_pipelining,    reject_non_fqdn_sender,    reject_unknown_sender_domain,    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,    reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,  check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:2501,    permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_domains = riminifar.it
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And this is my /etc/postfix/transport:

```
central.mydomain.tld        smtp:[srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld]
someotherdomain.org         smtp:[srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld]
yadomain.it                  smtp:[srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld]
xad.central.mydomain.tld        smtp:[srv-internal.central.mydomain.tld]
test.central.mydomain.tld        smtp:[10.10.15.101]
```

Now, ***Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table*** seems that relay server (mailgw) "thinks" that "pec.central.mydomain.tld" is one of its subdomain, so it searches for recipient user into its relay_recipient_maps, while it shouldn't IMHO.

I expected this behaviour if I put ".central.mydomain.tld" (with initial dot!) in my transport table, but I really have "central.mydomain.tld", so, reading manuals, it should only consider the domain name, and not also subdomains.

I greatly appreciate if somebody could suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter that's you should aware of is [parent_domain_matches_subdomains](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#parent_domain_matches_subdomains).

> A list of Postfix features where the pattern "example.com" also matches subdomains of example.com, instead of requiring an explicit ".example.com" pattern. This is planned backwards compatibility: eventually, all Postfix features are expected to require explicit ".example.com" style patterns when you really want to match subdomains.

So, parent_domain_matches_subdomains holds the **list of domain that postfix should match its subdomain too even without (dot) in front of it**.

Unfortunately, the `relay_domains` parameter fall to that list.

```
# postconf parent_domain_matches_subdomains
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
```

And because your `relay_domains`contains `$mydomain` or **central.mydomain.tld**, postfix matches all subdomain of **central.mydomain.tld** as `relay_domains` not external ones.

---

[The solution](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Specifying-subdomains-in-relay-domains-tp51786p51787.html) is set `parent_domain_matches_subdomains` and don't  include relay_domains on those parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much, @masegaloeh. It worked like a charm!:)
Your explaination was very clear too Tnx again.

Comment: @gabolander If this works, please consider to [accepting](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) this answer, so the question isn't floating in un-answered pool

Comment: I did it already, thank you. (I cannot report it as useful, 'cause I need 15 as reputation and I don't have yet)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found the whiteliste for email-user under: /etc/postfix/relay_recipients
If your user isn't inside of these list he would never get an email.